# How to Install mactime utility

Tags: software-installation

How to install mac-time utility in Ubuntu 14.10

I am not sure if the software exits for Ubuntu

I want to change the

`0|\Avira.lnk (Shellbag)|0|0|0|0|0|1425834998|1425834998|-62135596800|1418486458`

to readable text

Comment: Can you explain what is that text an what does the so-called utility?

Comment: no idea :) that's something related to shellbags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/williballenthin/shellbags) or [this](https://github.com/appliedsec/forensicscanner/blob/master/plugins/shellbags.pl)?

They seems to parse shellbags.

#### EDIT:

---

Maybe [this](http://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=Mactime)?

Comment: ya I got the below line how to get the date form it ??

Comment: I've made a edit to my answer. If is what do you want, please accept my answer.

Comment: *.Did it work?*